# While building libcxx using clang-cl, I get CMake error "include could not find load file: AddLLVM"?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, clang, llvm, libc++

I have just successfully built `llvm`, `clang` and `lld` on msvc build tool 2017 with windows 10 sdk.

I tried to build `libcxx` next.

While I was doing cmake/ninja (with `clang-cl` of newly built clang), I got this:

```
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:72 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AddLLVM


CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:74 (configure_lit_site_cfg):
  Unknown CMake command "configure_lit_site_cfg".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I did also pass this parameter to cmake

`-DLLVM_PATH="C:/llvm"`

Is this because I built `llvm` wrong?

---

### UPDATE

I already fixed this by

`-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="C:/llvm-master/cmake/modules`

Comment: Hi,

I have been trying to build clang using cmake and I am getting a similar error except it is not able to load file AddClang.. Where can I specify the path to AddClang?

Comment: @Tehreem That's weird. I never confronted that error. Well, as `AddLLM` is a module part of `llvm`'s own cmake, `AddClang` is likewise the same thing ==> [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/cmake/modules). I guess you can just add that path to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.

Comment: I checked out everything again and performed a clean build. Things are fine now so I must have missed some step earlier. However, I am facing new issues, Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53736152/1430961